# Azureml Web Service - How to create a Rest Service from an Experiment to be consumed by a mobile app?

Tags: json, web-services, azure, webforms, azure-machine-learning-service

I've looked all over the google and stackoverflow for the answer but I cant seem to find it. I'm trying to get the output from an azure experiment to an app. I've made the app using `ibuildapp` and google forms. How can I use the inputs from the google form, pass it to azure and get an output to display on the app?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your model from your app you want to create a rest service. See here.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-publish-a-machine-learning-web-service/

Then you will consume this rest serivce from your app using a standard http client. Sample code is available here.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-consume-web-services/

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for this. But when I copy and paste the code in C#  on Visual Studio, I'm getting a lot of errors. There is no tutorial and how exactly to implement the web service online. Can you please help

Comment: Follow the first link to create a rest service, you will be provided with a page to test this rest service. then modify the code in the 2nd link to connect to your service, you will have to provide more detail in your question about specifically which steps from the guides you are stuck for me to help

Comment: Hi Dan,
I'm really new to this so please sorry in advance for any silly question. 
I'm pasting this code onto visual studio. I have made a form in VisualStudio and I'm pasting the c# code that i got on api help in form.aspx.cs . Is that the correct way to use the api help code

Comment: I've pasted the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703378/error-on-following-code-from-azure-ml