# Error on following code from Azure ml

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, asp.net-web-api

Im getting multiple errors from the code specified by Microsoft Azure for its c# implementation of machine learning.
Can't seem to figure out the error

I've installed the Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`. I was getting an error when I used `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`
 command. So I used `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 4.0.30506` to install an earlier version.

```
namespace CallRequestResponseService
{

    public class StringTable
    {
        public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
        public string[,] Values { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait();
        }

        static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var scoreRequest = new
                {

                    Inputs = new Dictionary<string, StringTable> () 
                    { 
                        { 
                            "input1", 
                            new StringTable() 
                            {
                                ColumnNames = new string[] {"name", "age"},
                                Values = new string[,] {  { "value", "0" },  { "value", "0" } }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { }
                };
                const string apiKey = "abc123"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Bearer", apiKey);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/095906590a604077a98678e5d7fc69a0/services/b875062b548b41b884a490724c3cb71c/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true");

                // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
                // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
                // For instance, replace code such as:
                //      result = await DoSomeTask()
                // with the following:
                //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

                    // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting "; expected" on the following lines of code:

1) static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService

2) HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

3) string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

4)string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);